# Voice Recognition with Lotus Script

Tags: voice-recognition, lotusscript

I am trying to create a Voice Recognition software with Lotus Script. I looked around but have no idea where to begin. Any suggestions? Thank you. I looke

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case, look for a solution in Java and implement it as a plugin for the client or kind of COM object.